# Why computer vision is computationally hard?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

The recent most technological themselves could not reach the biological vision systems in terms of accuracy and response time? Insects with little computing power are so much accurate in image processing and act accordingly almost instantly(Ex Bee,fly). What kind of algorithm/architecture they are using? What are the challenges in mimicking biological vision systems? 
Point me to proper resources and links if possible.

Comment: `Insects with little computing power are so much accurate in image processing` - citation needed.

Comment: Peter Corke Robot Vision lecture -1 Bee example (He says the present machines have more computational power than a bee's brain)

Comment: Does he cite his source for that?

Comment: Book : Ray Kurzweil - Singularity is near. Just google 'Exponential growth of computing- Ray Kurzweil'

Comment: This is a really interesting question, but I'm not sure it's a good fit for Stack Overflow since it's likely to involve some amount of speculation rather than giving definitive answers. (My own thoughts? We still understand very little about vision systems and vision processing in biological systems, since we're still working on figuring out how actual brains work. I'm guessing we still have a foundational breakthrough to make before we'll truly "get" how everything works.)

Answer (score 0):

According to a documentary series from NHK World, the single-lens eyes (man, mammals and vertebrates) are superior to multiple-lens eyes of insects when it comes to targeting prey. For self-defense, the multiple lens design is much better. In both cases, the brains's signal processing approach is parallel, whereas the computers are not truly parallel.

Simon Thorpe's publications are a good starting point.An example is:

Guyonneau R, Kirchner H, Thorpe SJ. 2006. Animals roll around the clock: the rotation invariance of ultrarapid visual processing. J Vis 6:1008-17